# connecting to AWS Elasticsearch to reboot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am getting my hands in AWS hosted Elastic search. Is it possible for me to connect to the ES via the instance its linked? and is it possible to reboot my elastic search cluster?

The AWS Cli don't have anything related to reboot and all i can try is http curl to my ES.

Comment: May I ask, why do you need to reboot?

Answer (score 6):

To reboot an AWS Elasticsearch cluster, the only way is to log a support ticket and they will schedule a reboot for you. You can't do it yourselves.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that but I thought there might be some way around it , so i can atleast do something that can shake the ES

Answer (score 5):

I had a "1 node ES" in a testing environment that was not connectable. I was able to get the "1 node cluster" to "reboot" by increasing the number of nodes from 1 to 2. Then reducing the number of nodes from 2 to 1, and hoping it removed the one I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

You can also increase the size of the EBS a little bit, just to force a new ES cluster be created with the new size. The data will be migrated to the node data without downtime. This will behavior as a "reboot".

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what are you trying to achieve with reboot. One of the reasons we had to reboot cluster is as a temporary fix to continuous growth of GC cold collection (time as well as frequency). 
In order to achieve it, you can scale cluster up for short period of time and then back down (i.e. change instance type) which will bring another fleet of instances under the hood. 
This change should be seemless, so there shouldn't be any downtime (more details here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains.html). 
In terms of effort it's very low - `terraform apply` or manual change via console take just few minutes of time. This option comes very handy when the problem is time-sensitive and AWS support ticket make take days.